# stop a loop if model changes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, loops, activemodel

I'm trying to exit from a loop if model changes.

having the `status` attribute:

```
@model.status = 'started'

(0..100).each do |i|
  return if status == 'stopped'
  sleep(10)  
  # my taks...
end
```

the problem is, once is `started` changes in the model are not reflected within the loop, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to query the status inside the loop so that it gets an updated status.

```
(0..100).each do |i|
  status = Model.find(:id).status
  return if status == 'stopped'
  sleep(10)  
  # my taks...
end
```

Comment: `self.reload` would be better than `status = Model.find(:id).status`. It refreshes the model from the database. You could even write, `return if self.reload.status == 'stopped'`